# Get list of records having name starting with specific value and ignore in case of other values for different rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I'm trying to get the Col A records based on the first character on Col B. If the first character in Col B do matches with for all unique values of Col A, then the Col A value to be returned. If the first character in Col B does not match the other first values in Col B, then the col A value should not be returned. This is in Oracle SQL.

```
select T1.colA,count(*) from colTables T1 where T1.colA in (
select T2.colA from colTables T2 where T2.colB like '1%'
group by T2.colA)
group by T1.colA;



Col A | Col B
    101|12541
    101|15475
    101|19874
    102|12544
    102|22549
    102|12537
    103|22549
    103|28747
    104|72549
    104|82549
    104|82549
    105|12549
    105|12531
    105|12589
    106|75448
    106|71544
```

My query gives the following output

```
  ColA | Count
    101|3
    102|3
    105|3
```

but I want the output to be

```
   ColA| Count
    101|3
    105|3
```

Also.. I am checking if there is any means where I can omit `T2.colB like '1%'`  to get the output in the following way

```
   ColA| Count
    101|3  -- All values in col B starts with 1
    103|2  -- All values in col B starts with 2
    105|3  -- All values in col B starts with 1
    106|2  -- All values in col B starts with 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all `colB` values to start with a `1`, then:

```
select t.colA, count(*)
from colTables t
group by t.colA
having sum(case when t.colB like '1%' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

You could phrase this in other ways as well, such as:

```
having min(t.colB) >= '1' and
       max(t.colB) < '2'
```

If you just want that the `colB` values start with the same letter for all `colA`, use:

```
having min(substr(t.colB, 1, 1)) = max(substr(t.colB, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Good grief, I forgot it could be this simple. I always see you can sense what the OP is asking even if their problem description is too long yet not clear enough, like the island-and-gap problem I saw yesterday. Your solution is good, I would just write it as `sum(case when t.colB like '1%' then 1 end)`, I feel 0 in SUM is cargo-culting. Or more semantical, yes `SUM` could be used instead of `COUNT`, however, COUNT has better semantics for er.. counting :) `count(case when t.colB like '1%' then t.colB end)`

Comment: If OP uses RDBMS that supports FILTER clause for aggregate: `having count(colB) filter(where colB like '1%') = count(colA)`. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iquHToVTGz8JxnWSaT2ChD/5

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, this works like a charm having min(substr(t.colB, 1, 1)) = max(substr(t.colB, 1, 1)) for any given condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  "cola" varchar(100),
  "colb" varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO tbl
  ("cola", "colb")
VALUES
  ('101', '12541'),
  ('101', '15475'),
  ('101', '19874'),
  ('102', '12544'),
  ('102', '22549'),
  ('102', '12537'),
  ('103', '22549'),
  ('103', '28747'),
  ('104', '72549'),
  ('104', '82549'),
  ('104', '82549'),
  ('105', '12549'),
  ('105', '12531'),
  ('105', '12589'),
  ('106', '75448'),
  ('106', '71544');
```

**Query**

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iquHToVTGz8JxnWSaT2ChD/4

```
select cola, count(*)
from tbl
group by cola
having (cola, count(*))
in (                      
  select 
      cola, count(*)
  from tbl
  where colb like '1%'
  group by cola
)
order by cola;
```

Output:

```
| cola | count |
| ---- | ----- |
| 105  | 3     |
| 101  | 3     |
```

Another approach, works on RDBMS that does not supports to tuple in `IN` clause. Use EXISTS:

```
select y.cola, count(*) as y_count
from tbl y
group by y.cola
having exists
(
  select 
      null -- does not matter
  from tbl x
  -- this matters
  where x.cola = y.cola 
     and x.colb like '1%'
  group by x.cola
  having count(x.cola) = count(y.cola)
)
order by y.cola;
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael. This works with the given scenario for starting with 1.